# Animate UIButton with Image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a `UIButton` which contains an image. I want to make an animation which lets the button become bigger while keeping the origin of the button at the same point.

Here is what I did:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: { () -> Void in

   button.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1)

}, completion: { finished in
  println("annimation done")
})
```

This works but the transformation does not look so good. It does not scale around the center of the button. What this animation does is the following. First, the button is moved to the right and then it is scaled. Hier is an image of the button. The button is the thumb and it is pinned to the left edge of the green box.

[image]

**How do I have to align the `UIButton` that the scale animation is performed smoothly?**

Edit: The green box should contain two buttons which should be layouted as shown below.

[image]

Comment: You have to put thumb in centre of green.Because scaling do from centre of view but your thumb button can't scale left side because it pinned to left.

Comment: @bhoomi I cannot put the button in the center because there are two buttons in the green box which should have a fixed space between each other.